# Using Primefaces dataexporter with email

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-dataexporter

I have got a working primefaces dataexporter. Now the client wants the possibility to send the exported document by email in stead of downloading

Though I haven't implemented it yet, I think it is possible to send the email with attached file in the postprocessor callback. The problem lays in the fact that whatever I do in the postprocessor callback, the document always downloads. What I mean is, I don't want to also download the document when I am sending it by email. The download is redundant.

So the question is: is there a way to stop the exported document to download?